# React Native PayPal integration without server dependency?

Tags: react-native, paypal

I have tried with using Web view and having a Node server with paypal-rest-sdk as backend.

The flow seems to be a work around. Is there any way to directly integrate the Paypal with React Native code without any server calls or web views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a React question -- if no server is used, then you would be doing a client-only HTML/JS integration such as this one: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

That's possible to do. It would all be happening in a full mobile web experience, which then becomes the PayPal Checkout.

---

If your question was whether it's technically possible to do "server"-style REST API calls from a purely native React app, please put that thought out of your mind. Your 'secret' API key should never be in the possession of a client-side App.